# Sonar - Fail to request server version | HTTP Status 404

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I'm setting up a sonar system for Java. My local test SonarServer 4.0 successfully connect and process my antscript (I'm using "sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar"). But my target server 3.7.3 won't even provide the server version.

I tried the given http://... from the given errormessage and my browser (firefox) is showing the correct server version.

Can someone help me out with this one ? Thx :)

```
PATH2ANTSCRIPT\build.xml:159: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request server version
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request server version
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.downloadVersion(ServerVersion.java:49)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.version(ServerVersion.java:38)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.is37Compatible(ServerVersion.java:58)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.checkVersionAndDownload(JarDownloader.java:36)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:53)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:48)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Status returned by url : 'http://URL2SERVER.net/sonar/api/server/version' is invalid : 404
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:94)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.downloadVersion(ServerVersion.java:47)
    ... 26 more
```

EDIT: Sorry but after a restart I can't reproduce this error above. Now I can't even connect to the server :O After some restarts later I still get this error - for not connecting

```
BUILD FAILED
PATH2ANTSCRIPT\build.xml:160: org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
Caused by: org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1392)
    at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.ok(HttpRequest.java:1417)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:93)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.downloadVersion(ServerVersion.java:47)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.version(ServerVersion.java:38)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.is37Compatible(ServerVersion.java:58)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.checkVersionAndDownload(JarDownloader.java:36)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:53)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:48)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1390)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.header(HttpRequest.java:1903)
    at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.contentType(HttpRequest.java:2308)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:89)
... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but the server was secured to allow only http requests. So the problem was an adminstration problem only.

Answer (score 1):

seems that your server can not connect, you can do the two following operation:
1. check your sonar server port had been listening..
2. restart the sonar server, if your environment need mysql first, restart mysql first.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue and resolved it. Check the SonarQube server's following properties (you may find it in - SONAR_INSTALATION_DIR/conf/sonar.properties)

```
sonar.web.host=localhost
sonar.web.port=9000
sonar.web.context=/sonar
```

Then check your Sonar-runner's configuration(You may find it in - SONAR-RUNNER-INSTALLATION-DIR/conf/sonar-runner.properties)

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/sonar
```

Make sure the sonar.host.url was composed using the above three properties from the SonarQube's properties as shown here. In your case make sure you have the values as explained here.