# Sonar - Fail to request server version | HTTP Status 404 /

Tags: sonarqube

With each run done by console or by Jenkins throws me the following error:

```
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_51 Oracle Corporation (32-bit)
Linux 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.i686 i386
INFO: Runner configuration file: /usr/local/sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /opt/apps/php-sonar-runner/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "es_ES", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /opt/apps/php-sonar-runner/./.sonar
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.042s
Final Memory: 0M/28M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Fail to request server version
ERROR: Caused by: Status returned by url : 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:9000/api/server/version' is invalid : 404
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: The same question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889962/sonar-fail-to-request-server-version-http-status-404

Answer (score 3):

Open the URL 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:9000/api/server/version' in a browser, see if it gives you a 404 error. If so, you need to find the right path to Sonar root on the remote server, maybe 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:9000/sonar/'?

When you have the full URL of Sonar, update the `sonar.host.url` property in your pom accordingly. See [full documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) for more details.

Comment: The url is accessible to me in browser but giving issue while running the build in jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

Check the value of `sonar.web.context` = `/myPath` maybe you have some path and you configure other path in your url at your jenkis, tfs, etc. That is the reason you get an 404 error.

In your example you should not have that value configurated or without a value.

'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:9000`/myPath`/api/server/version

Answer (score 1):

In your `sonar-runner.properties` file

define #--- Default SonarQube sever as give below

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/sonar
```

Also cross check in `sonar.properties` file i.e

```
sonar.web.port=9000
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1
sonar.web.context=/sonar
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who may have run into the 404.   Another thing that could cause this exact error is if the sonarqube instance was recently updated and the /setup step is in progress or is pending.   The /api/server version won't be accessible until this is complete.   Certainly a rare edge case, but can happen  ...