# SonarQube local installation not starting

Tags: sonarqube

I tried to install sonarqube as discribed here with the zip method: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/get-started-2-minutes/

Further than I try to execute on Windows:

```
C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat
```

Unfortunately the server doesn't start. I checked the logs (below) and receive an error. Has someone an idea how I can fix it? Thanks!

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2022.02.03 13:28:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\KBData\sonarqube-kbecom\temp
2022.02.03 13:28:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:3235]
2022.02.03 13:28:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\KBData\sonarqube-kbecom\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\bin\java -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\KBData\sonarqube-kbecom\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.tmpdir=C:\KBData\sonarqube-kbecom\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -Dcom.redhat.fips=false -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\KBData\sonarqube-kbecom\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\KBData\sonarqube-kbecom\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
2022.02.03 13:28:24 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2022.02.03 13:28:24 ERROR app[][o.s.a.p.EsManagedProcess] Failed to check status
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [http://127.0.0.1:9001], URI [/], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2695)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2137)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.ClusterClient.health(ClusterClient.java:151)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getClusterHealthStatus(EsConnectorImpl.java:64)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkStatus(EsManagedProcess.java:97)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:82)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.isOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:67)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler.refreshState(ManagedProcessHandler.java:220)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler$EventWatcher.run(ManagedProcessHandler.java:285)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [http://127.0.0.1:9001], URI [/], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.getValue(BaseFuture.java:257)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:244)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2692)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [http://127.0.0.1:9001], URI [/], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:331)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.access$1800(RestClient.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:381)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:377)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:448)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:338)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2022.02.03 13:28:25 ERROR app[][o.s.a.p.EsManagedProcess] Failed to check status
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [http://127.0.0.1:9001], URI [/], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2695)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2137)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.ClusterClient.health(ClusterClient.java:151)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getClusterHealthStatus(EsConnectorImpl.java:64)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkStatus(EsManagedProcess.java:97)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:82)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.isOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:67)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler.refreshState(ManagedProcessHandler.java:220)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler$EventWatcher.run(ManagedProcessHandler.java:285)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [http://127.0.0.1:9001], URI [/], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958812/sonar-fail-to-request-server-version-http-status-404) SO question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now changed the port of `sonar.search.port` as well as `sonar.web.port`. Now it's working.

Comment: I have the same question as you. But I still wonder. How did you actually solve this problem.

Comment: Have look here: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-local-installation-not-starting/57588 - Just needed to change sonar.search.port as well as sonar.web.port to a non used port - than it worked.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. I up vote your question and answer.